# Проверка на уникальность строки в выборке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  SID NVARCHAR(128) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MEMBER (
  MemberID INT NOT NULL,
  EMAddress NVARCHAR(240) NULL
)
```

Задача - из таблицы `MEMBER` производим `INSERT` не повторяющихся строк по таблице `USER` в табличную переменную столбцов MemberID и EMAddress и вставляем в таблицу `USER` в столбцы `ID, SID`. Иначе в столбце `EMAddress` таблицы `Member` есть не уникальные значения, которые необходимо отсеять перед `INSERT` в табличную переменную.

Были предприняты следующие попытки:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.MemberID,m.EMaddress FROM MEMBER m   
      EXCEPT 
SELECT u.ID,u.SID FROM USER u

--------------------------------------------
543 rows

SELECT DISTINCT m.MemberID FROM MEMBER m   
      EXCEPT 
SELECT u.ID FROM USER u

--------------------------------------------
542 rows
```

Тем самым `DISCTINCT` не подходит если идет выборка нескольких столбцов, ведь они проверяются на разность парой `m.MemberID,m.EMaddress`.

Как быть?

Comment: *в столбце EMAddress таблицы Member есть не уникальные значения, которые необходимо отсеять перед INSERT в табличную переменную* Ну вот есть две записи с совпадающим EMAddress и разными MemberID... и как решить, какой из MemberID отбросить, а?

Comment: Не принципиально, любой MemberID отбросить

Comment: Ну тогда группировка по EMAddress и MIN() либо MAX() по MemberID.

Comment: Спасибо @Akina

Вышло следующее:

  SELECT MAX(m.MemberID),m.EMaddress FROM MEMBER m
    GROUP BY m.EMAddress
      EXCEPT 
SELECT u.ID,u.SID FROM USER u

Answer (score 0):

Так будет работать:

```
SELECT max(m.MemberID), m.EMaddress 
FROM MEMBER m 
GROUP BY m.EMAddress 
EXCEPT 
SELECT u.ID, u.SID 
FROM USER u
```